# Issues with Schema Registry through Logstash - Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, rubygems, logstash, confluent-schema-registry

I keep getting errors when trying to connect to my Schema Registry through Logstash output Avro serialization into Kafka. I think it can't handle well the exception the server gives. I can't get the schema and the program stops.

I've tried to modify client.rb on line 127 to change the way it raises the exception but without success on it, may I have to recompile everything? It's my first time with Ruby, I'm on Java/Kotlin side...

I've confirmed the access to the URI of the SR is working from my machine, I even have access to the UI of SR without issues and can reach the schema without problems. I've tried also going through schema_id but the same issue appears.

I've also put an issue in the GitHub of logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry from Revpoint, but I've seen there are other issues without answer there, so I put the issue here hoping some of you with Ruby background can help me solve this situation. Many thanks in advance.

`Logstash.javapipeline ][main] Pipeline worker error, the pipeline will be stopped {:pipeline_id=>"main", :error=>"(ArgumentError) wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)", :exception=>Java::OrgJrubyExceptions::ArgumentError, :backtrace=>["org.jruby.RubyException.exception(org/jruby/RubyException.java:129)", "C_3a_.datos.logstash.vendor.bundle.jruby.$2_dot_5_dot_0.gems.schema_registry_minus_0_dot_1_dot_1.lib.schema_registry.client.request(C:/datos/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.1/lib/schema_registry/client.rb:127)", "uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.start(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:914)", "uri_3a_classloader_3a_.META_minus_INF.jruby_dot_home.lib.ruby.stdlib.net.http.start(uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/net/http.rb:609)", "RUBY.request(C:/datos/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/schema_registry-0.1.1/lib/schema_registry/client.rb:101)", ... ...`

My logstash config is the following:

```
 file {
   path => "C:/datos/logstash/out/logfile.json"
   codec => "json_lines"
 }
 kafka {
   acks => "1"
   bootstrap_servers => "my Kafka servers"
   topic_id => "my Kafka topic"
   compression_type => "gzip"
   retries => 0
   codec => avro_schema_registry {
     endpoint=> "schema registry URI"
     subject_name => "the AVRO schema in SR"
     schema_version => "5"
   }
   value_serializer => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
 }
```

Edit: I've tested the process both from Unix (where I was developing at the beginning) and from my local Windows with a dummy input with the same result (I have also connectivity to the SR server both from Unix and Win). Anything I can try, I can do it quick in my Win deployment.

Comment: Is this your complete logstash config? If so, this is wrong, you need a `input {}` block and a `output {}` block.

Comment: no, it's only my output block, if I remove the kafka coded for the schema registry everything works fine, it's only when I go into the codec when it fails